# Pass value of input field to flask filter

Tags: python, flask

I would like to pass the content of an input filed into a flask filter as such

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" name="myInput" />

{% for file in items|filter_list(myInput) %}
                            <a class="collapse-item" href="{{url_for('report', platform='ios', app_bundle=file)}}">{{file}}</a>
                        {% endfor %}
```

The for loop should contain the result when all items have been filtered by based on `myInput`

Comment: by `myInput` you're expecting to have the value that user typed in that input? You have to do this in frontend. By the time that the template is rendered, there was no user input yet

Comment: You can (1), send a request with the input, or (2) use javascript to filter files